# Hex string variable to hex value conversion in python

Tags: python, string, hex

I have a variable call hex_string. The value could be '01234567'. Now I would like to get a hex value from this variable which is 0x01234567 instead of string type. The value of this variable may change. So I need a generic conversion method.

Comment: The expectation of this question is that you have a hex value in ascii representation and you would like to convert the ascii representation of a hex value to a actual hex value, however the selected answer assumes a conversion from the string to a different value. The question should have really been how do I convert an Ascii value to it's hexidecimal representation (which the selected answer does). Specifically I was expecting a solution with a resulting hex value of 0x01234567

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you might be mixing up numbers and their representations. `0x01234567` and `19088743` are the exact same thing. `"0x01234567"` and `"19088743"` are not (note the quotes).

To go from a string of hexadecimal characters, to an integer, use [`int(value, 16)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int).

To go from an integer, to a string that represents that number in hex, use [`hex(value)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex).

```
>>> a = 0x01234567
>>> b = 19088743
>>> a == b
True
>>> hex(b)
'0x1234567'
>>> int('01234567', 16)
19088743
>>>
```

Comment: The question doesn't seem to match the answer, the original question implied that  
a = "FF"
print hex(a)
>> 0xFF
however none of the answers seem to solve that problem (including this one).

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to edit worth a darn, but basically set a to a STRING value of FF, then do a hex operation on it, then print that, SHOULD result in printing 0xFF, however it usually results in an error complaining hex can't convert that value

Comment: @onaclov2000 The answer wants to say that instead of saving the value to a string and then convert it back to hex, you save the value as an integer and then convert it later to hex !

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> int('01234567', 16)
19088743
```

This is the same as:

```
>>> 0x01234567
19088743
```

Comment: `int('0x01234567',16)` also works fine, no need to remove the `0x` part.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I didn't remove anything, the question says *The value could be '01234567'*

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a
'01234567'
>>> hex(int(a))
'0x12d687'
>>>
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the proper 'pythonic' way to do this but here was what I came up with.

```
def hex_string_to_bin_string(input):
   lookup = {"0" : "0000", "1" : "0001", "2" : "0010", "3" : "0011", "4" : "0100", "5" : "0101", "6" : "0110", "7" : "0111", "8" : "1000", "9" : "1001", "A" : "1010", "B" : "1011", "C" : "1100", "D" : "1101", "E" : "1110", "F" : "1111"}
   result = ""
   for byte in input:
      result =  result + lookup[byte]
   return result
def hex_string_to_hex_value(input):
   value = hex_string_to_bin_string(input)
   highest_order = len(value) - 1
   result = 0
   for bit in value:
      result = result + int(bit) * pow(2,highest_order)
      highest_order = highest_order - 1
   return hex(result)
print hex_string_to_hex_value("FF")
```

The result being

```
0xff
```

Also trying 
    print hex_string_to_hex_value("01234567")

results in

```
0x1234567L
```

Note: the L indicates the value falls into category of a "long" as far as I can tell based on the documentation from the python website (they do show that you can have a L value appended).
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex

```
>>> hex(255)
'0xff'
>>> hex(-42)
'-0x2a'
>>> hex(1L)
'0x1L'
```

Answer (score 0):

hex value is `<type 'long'>` while hex string is `<type 'str'>`. All operations on hex value are workable if type is changed to long from str.

```
long(hex_string,16)
```